# Discipline for a bloodline using tattoos

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

I would like to create a `Gangrel` bloodline for `Vampire: the Requiem`, that would embrace using tattoos. I have created a weakness, which was and now I would like to create a separate discipline. I am not a great fan of new disciplines, but I believe that it would be adequate for this bloodline. At this point I have following ideas:

1. Shaping - kindred can shape his tattoos to hold some information (therefore he doesn't need to roll Int + Comp to remember it)
2. Library - all the kindred hears is stored as small bits of information inside his tattoos, therefore he gets +1 for each dot of discipline for knowledge based tests
3. Camouflage - Kindred can shape his tats in a way, that they will act as a camouflage (+1 to stealth rolls for each dot), of course he needs to be naked to use this

What do you think about those? I need two more. Could you share some ideas for additional powers?

**Weakness**

Every time character increases level of a discipline it must create a tattoo (and spend point of willpower, to keep it that way), that symbolizes that. Also, any other character can roll Int + Investigation, while seeing all tattoos. For each success he gets information about: virtue, vice, humanity level, blood potency level, highest level discipline he/she didn't know before. I wanted this weakness to emphasize that tattoos describe character's achievements or personality.

Comment: The weakness appears to have dropped out of the post; would you care to add it back in?

Comment: I have described the weakness, though it wasn't dropped out. I just didn't considered it important to mention.

Comment: Have a look at the dark ages Lhiannan: http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Lhiannan they have a unique discipline called Ogham that involves (at some levels) daubing yourself in blood, much like a tattoo mark - this might be helpful

Answer (score 3):

My WoD knowledge is very limited; but, I wanted to contribute some thematic ideas. A tattoo is not just information, writing, or lines. It can be; but, often a tattoo (particularly a ritual tattoo) is a symbol of something powerful, personal, or familiar. I think it would be cool to have tattoo powers along this theme. A couple of ideas:

- `Living Ink`: You possess a life-size tattoo of an animal you choose. When this power is activated, the animal detaches itself from your body, and comes alive, acting under your command. When not activated, the animal returns to its tattoo form.
- `Symbol of Blessing`: You bear the symbol of a powerful spirit that watches over you. The symbol may represent a religious icon, mentor spirit, personal totem, or the like. (I would suggest applying some small bonus appropriate to the character's faith or discipline. Ex: +1 an attack, defense, or healing check)
- `Symbol of Luck`: You wear the mark of Lady Luck, herself. Fortune smiles upon you. You win at gambling games where chance is a key element. (If another character has the same power, you might have some kind of opposed test).
- `Nice Ink`: Your tattoos can be shaped to charm, impress, or inspire fear. (Gain some bonus to social interactions)

Answer (score 3):

I think this lends itself more towards rituals than simple discipline, like Theban, Cruac, Gilded Cage, etc.  Base it on something like Presence + Crafts and a willpower to activate to represent willing the tattoos into the appropriate shape to enact the ritual (also prevents double dipping with other rituals that use Int or Manipulation).

Then have rituals at the various dots, you get one for "free" when you advance the power, then buying more costs 2 x ritual level.

Using the example given by the other answers, you may see something like

• Shaping - kindred can shape his tattoos to hold some information, therefore he doesn't need to roll Int + Comp to remember it.  The character can hold one piece of information at a time per dot in the power.

• Symbol of Defense: You bear the symbol of a powerful spirit that watches over you. The symbol may represent a religious icon, mentor spirit, personal totem, or the like. This grants +2 defense while active.

•• Library - all the kindred hears is stored as small bits of information inside his tattoos.  Choose a mental skill.  The character gets an equipment bonus to that skill equal to the number of dots in the power.  This ritual can be purchased more than once, each time it represents a different mental skill.  This equipment bonus can not be combined with another equipment bonus representing documentation or research materials (e.g. Chapter Library, etc)

•• Symbol of Luck: You wear the mark of Lady Luck, herself. Fortune smiles upon you. On your next check, roll twice and keep the better result. For example, on a Strength(3) + Brawl(4) check, roll 7 dice and count the successes.  Then roll all 7 dice again and count the successes.  Keep the set with greater successes.  (For MET, pull two cards, keep the higher card.)

••• Camouflage - Kindred can shape his tats in a way, that they will act as a camouflage (+1 to stealth rolls for each dot), of course he needs to be naked to use this.  This cannot be combined with another discipline, such as Obfuscate •••.

•••• Living Ink: You possess a life-size tattoo of an animal you choose. When this power is activated, the animal detaches itself from your body, and comes alive, acting under your command. When not activated, the animal returns to its tattoo form.  The animal has the same stats as a normal animal of its kind.  The animal must be chosen at the time this ritual is learned.  The ritual may be purchased more than once, each one represents an additional animal the character can summon.  The character can heal damage to the animal while it is in tattoo form by spending blood following the same rules as healing himself.  If the animal is killed, this ritual must be repurchased. (compare to retainer, but can summon and dismiss at will, and has full control over the animal. It would be a 5 dot ritual, if animal retainers weren't already so limited)

Add ones that duplicate encyclopedic knowledge, eidetic memory, and so forth

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely going to give this more thought over the weekend, but here are my initial ideas.

- There's an interesting interaction between this discipline and the Gangrel clan flaw: the first two powers respectively remove the need for one Intelligence-based knowledge roll and give a growing bonus to another. For that reason, I might swap or combine the first and second levels; their benefit is equivalent to `Eidetic Memory`, a •••• creation only merit, which means their power level should be watched.
- Conversely, the ••• level seems underpowered. Compare with other discipline powers of similar rank: Mask of a Thousand Faces, Entrancement, Forgetful Mind. If it were me, I'd make *this* the •-rank power.

Comment: Yes, 3 level is underpowered because unique disciplines should be less powerful than the common ones. Also the weakness I have in mind is less powerful, than usual. I wanted to balance those two.

Comment: Yes, discipline is somehow countering Gangrel weakness and that's the point of it - some wise Gangrel wanted to find to way, to stop forgetting things.